# QuickReport on Delphi Sydney 10.4.1

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I have a license for QuickReport components (I have files for Delphi 10.3). Now I want to migrate to Delphi 10.4.1 but I see the lead author of QR is dead and component development has stopped. For me it is a disaster, I will not be able to switch to something new in a short time. Do you have any way to run QuickReport 6 on Delphi 10.4.1?

Comment: There is a thread in the German Delphi-PRAXiS about a resurrection of QuickReport - unfortunately in German. Despite announced for October/November there has been no new version yet.
https://www.delphipraxis.net/205782-quickreport-es-geht-weiter.html

Comment: I ported QR 5.06 from Berlin to Sydney without much effort. If you have a license, you have source code. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Hi guys, I have installed the QR6 in Delphi 10.4 but I had to modify the QRWDesignDXE10_3.dproj  project, changing the Build Control option to "Rebuild as needed" because of the following error:

>>>> [dcc32 Fatal Error] QRWRunDXE10_3_w64.dpk(30): E2225 Never-build package 'rtl' must be recompiled  <<<<
And now I have to modify my projects to the same option but it became a nightmare. Is there a way to avoid this error and get the option back to default "Explicit rebuild"?

Answer (score 1):

I purchased QuickReports version 6 as an upgrade from 5.06.

It's basically the same 2016 version after 2019 modifications and recompiled in 2021 for compatibility with Sydney and Alexandria (the source codes are basically the same, they differ in some minor details).

There is a minimum of new things.

I believe that (some) intermediate version was used because until recently QBS did not have the QuickReport source codes the same across all unicode versions of Delphi (each version of Delphi had its own and different installer). Some things, already fixed in 2013 and 2016, are missing.

1. Are there any significant differences between 5.06 and 6 that, that I missed, that I should be aware of?
2. Why are previously fixed bugs in the 2013 and 2016 versions not present in the current version; is it possible that Quick Reports 6 is not descended from 2013 and 2016 versions?

Answer (score 0):

I have bought **QuickReport** with Source and compiled it with `Delphi Sidney`. Along with some other components related to it, some of them I own since `Delphi 5`.